# How to get the directory from which a Python executable is being called?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

A Python 3 program has been compiled into an exe file called `myapp.exe`, and is located at a `C:\path\to\myapp.exe` or at `/path/to/myapp.exe`  using pyinstaller.

Another program calls the executable from some other arbitrary location anywhere on the same machine.  For example, from `C:\another\arbitrary\path\` or from `/another/arbitrary/path/`.

What specific syntax must be added to the code that gets compiled into `myapp.exe` in order for `myapp.exe` to be able to programmatically refer to the other arbitrary path from which `myapp.exe` is being called at any given point in time?

##### Current Code

The current code for the `myapp.py` file that gets compiled into `myapp.exe` is:

```
print('Hello World!')
```

##### Desired Code

The code I am seeking should look something like:

```
yourCallingDirectoryAtAnotherArbitraryPath = code requested in this OP
print('Hello, you are calling from ', yourCallingDirectoryAtAnotherArbitraryPath)
```

This must work for any OS.

Comment: If it the calling application is identical to the current working directory, you could try `os.getcwd()`

Comment: You can't do this in Python.

Comment: What is wrong with `os.path.abspath(".")`?

Comment: Well, if there was some tool that could determine the information you want, you could certainly call it from Python that way. Again, I know of no way to get the information (with any tool). You're assuming that the executable is being called "from a directory", which really has no meaning beyond possibly an association the OS may be making on a per-process basis — see [current working directory (CWD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory).

Comment: Does this answer your question? "[How to know/change current directory in Python shell?](//stackoverflow.com/q/8248397/90527l)", "[Find path to currently running file](//stackoverflow.com/q/1296501/90527)", "[Python os.getcwd paths](//stackoverflow.com/q/1764322/90527)", ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually the more difficult job is for the executable to find out where it is stored itself.  When you start a program, the current directory is available to the executable with the shorthand pathname `.`

So to get the absolute path of the current directory, it is as easy as:

```
import os
print (os.path.abspath("."))
```